# Caffe draw_net.py unable to draw VGG-16 from prototxt file

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I'm using the following command to draw the block diagram of networks from prototxt files in caffe

```
python draw_net.py <filename.prototxt> <output.png>
```

This works fine if I use Alexnet, BVLC Caffenet or even RCNN. But when I use VGG-16 file, it gives a blank output image of size 11x11. No error is thrown. I have verified the paths too. All the files are taken from the [Caffe Model Zoo](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Model-Zoo#models-used-by-the-vgg-team-in-ilsvrc-2014). I'm using the Caffe taken from the [master branch](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe).

Answer (score 1):

Your `VGG16` file may contain old type definition of layers:

```
layers {
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1_1"
  name: "conv1_1"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
  }
}
```

To make it work, you need to make use of the new API of **type**:

```
layer {
  bottom: "conv1_1"
  top: "conv1_2"
  name: "conv1_2"
  type: "Convolution"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
}
```

Comment: there is an automatic tool for this conversion in `tools/update_net_proto_text`